# How to find the circle in the given image using opencv with python

Tags: python, opencv

[image]

How i can find the circle in this image?

my code that not working

```
        img = cv2.imread('captcha.png')
        img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
        cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

        circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=20,maxRadius=0)

        circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
        for i in circles[0,:]:
            cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
            cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

        cv2.imshow('Circles',cimg)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Please provide more context

Comment: Threshold on red using cv2.inRange(). Then do Hough circles on the thresholded image.